# Turn off hover/active with touch events

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile, browser, touch

Having HTML document on tablet, when `div` element receive `touchstart` event, `:hover` and `:active` status seems to be activated and they stay active even finger is moved out of the element and `touchend` event is not called. How can I turn off hover/active status once finger is out of the element?

Comment: you could have an HTML class `no-touch` on `body` set/unset by the javascript, then modify the CSS to test the class.

Comment: if `touchend` is only triggered when the finger is lifted from the element, listen for the `touchend` on the `body`

Comment: @JanDvorak - I have no problem with listening on `touchend` for "click" event, but `:hover` and `:active` status stay freeze and so visual look. This is not about triggering event, but about css visual issue...

Comment: Disable hover styling if touch events are detected by toggling a class on `body`. I suppose the mouse pointer stays at the last touch location.

Comment: @JanDvorak - I don't want completely disable `:hover` style/look, I want to find a solution how to fix it. You are probably correct about mouse position...

Comment: disable :hover on `touchend` and enable on `touchstart`

Comment: @JanDvorak - But there is no `touchend` sometimes - that's a problem!

Comment: Even `body` can lose `touchend` events? How is that possible? P.S. Your username is hard to @notify.

Comment: one of touchend or touchcancel have to occur

Comment: @Asad when does `touchcancel` happen? When the touch leaves the viewport sideways?

Comment: @Asad - I wish, but unfortunately not...